# Como verificar si el numero aleatorio es el mismo al que ingresó el usuario

Tags: c++, funciones, booleano, vectores

Estoy haciendo un juego en C++ (con vectores dinámicos) para la gente con alzheimer, en la que se generan 2 números aleatorios del 0 al 9 que desaparecen después de unos segundos, si la persona ingresa los mismos dos numeros que se le mostraron, se van a generar 3 números aleatorios nuevamente y asi sucesivamente hasta que llegue a 10.

(ejemplo del juego: http://labpsi.mdp.edu.ar/WebFormTest/DigitosDirectosInversosTest.aspx?ID=1&tt=1) Lo empecé ayer, y me quede trabado en la parte para confirmar si el numero que ingreso el usuario es igual al aleatorio y aumentar la cantidad de números. Imagino que el error esta entre el bool y el main, si pueden aclárenme esa duda, gracias (en el código solo puse la parte del problema).

```
vector <int> generarVector(vector <int> random, int n);
void pedirNumeros(vector <int> nums, int n);
bool noRepetir(vector <int> VecNums, vector <int> random, int n);

int main() {
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Spanish");
    vector <int> lista, random, numeros;
    int secs, n = 2;

    lista = generarNumeros(lista);
    random = generarVector(random, n);
    pedirNumeros(numeros, n);
    if(noRepetir(numeros, random, n) == true) {
        pedirNumeros(numeros, n);
        generarVector(random, n);
        cout<<"Bien!\n";
        n++;
        } else {
        cout<<"Mal.\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}

vector <int> generarVector(vector <int> random, int n) {
    int i, j, c;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c = rand() % 10;
        random.push_back(c);
    } for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if(random[j] == random[j+1]) {
            random.pop_back();
            c = rand() % 10;
            random.push_back(c);
        }
    }
    return random;
}

bool noRepetir(vector <int> VecNums, vector <int> random, int n) {
    bool flag = false;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(VecNums[i] == random[i]) {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

void pedirNumeros(vector <int> nums, int n) {
    int i, num;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout<<"Número: ";
        cin>>num;
        nums.push_back(num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En C++, para generar números aleatorios, tienes a tu disposición la librería `random`. Esta librería es preferible sobre `rand`, función heredada de C:

```
// Generador aleatorio, es lento, se usa para inicializar otro generador más rápido
std::random_device seed;

// Generador más rápido
std::mt19937 generator(seed);

// Controla que los números aleatorios se distribuyan de forma uniforme en el rango 0-9
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,9);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    int numero = distribution(generator);
    colection.push_back(numero);
}
```

Por otro lado, ya que los números no admiten duplicados, sería recomendable usar el contenedor `std::set`. Este contenedor te proporciona dos ventajas básicas:

- No admite duplicados
- Los valores se guardan ordenados

Por otro lado, no hay necesidad de pasarle a `generaVector` un `std::vector`. Esta función únicamente necesita conocer el número de valores a generar

```
std::set<int> generarVector(int n)
{
    std::set<int> toReturn;

    std::random_device seed;
    std::mt19937 generator(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 9);

    while (toReturn.size() < n)
    {
        toReturn.insert(distribution(generator));
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

¿Cómo comprobamos ahora si los valores que introduzca el usuario coinciden con los generados? Facil, rellenamos otro `set` y comparamos ambas colecciones:

```
std::set<int> generados = generarVector(n);

std::set<int> usuario;
for( int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    int numero;
    std::cin >> numero;
    usuario.insert(numero);
}

// ...

if (usuario == generados)
    // Los vectores coinciden
```

Comment: La verdad desconocía que se podía hacer así, de todas maneras, necesito que no estén ordenados, por lo tanto `set` acá no me serviría, ¿No hay otra manera, parecida a lo que estaba haciendo yo de como verificar que son iguales? porque lo de hacer que no se repitan ya lo había conseguido, el problema es el anterior, igualmente gracias, voy a ver si lo puedo usar pero necesito que no estén ordenados y comprobar si son iguales.

Comment: Por cierto, supongo que cuando rellenas el vector manualmente, lo haces en el main, ¿no hay alguna manera de hacerlo con un procedimiento como hice arriba?

Comment: @MaxiV ¿Puedo preguntar por la razón que obliga a que los elementos no estén ordenados? En cuanto a lo de rellenar el vector, ese código lo puedes meter en una función o dejarlo en el main. El código puedes ponerlo donde más te convenga (mejor en una función)

Comment: Por que me lo pide asi el ejercicio, es una tarea de la escuela, igualmente gracias, voy a ver como hago para encontrar la solución.